# Old computer and GeForce 9500 GS strange behavior

Tags: graphics-card

I have really old computer it is:

- Athlon x2 64,
- Motherboard MSI k9nu neo
- no-name power supplies 350W
- 3GB of ram
- GeForce 6600 SE PCI-E

My friend bought HP GeForce 9500 GS by mistake and he gave me it. It have 512MB of RAM and no additional power socket. My computer was running about 3 months without any problem with this card. After it I heard 1 long and 2 short beeps and in hardware manager I found error code 43 for graphics card. I removed 9500 and inserted old one, but I got the same result. I have 7300GT but it also reacts the same way.

I have another motherboard Foxconn M61PMV, I moved everything to this motherboard and installed this 9500 graphic card. Everything was running good for 3 days. Then my computer won't start until I removed 9500 graphics card. Computer is running on integrated graphics card, but is sometimes restart without any reason.

I already ordered new parts, but I have limited funds and I'm forced to use integrated graphics card( Intel G3420).

I'm wondering what cause this problem? Old power supplies or graphics card itself? Do you have any idea?

Comment: It sounds like the common thread is the power supply.